# React Native: Redux - How to properly update TextInput via event and have redux state update?

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs, react-redux

I am using Redux + React Native.

My Action set up is:

```
export function updateUsername(eventValue) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_USERNAME,
    username: eventValue
  }
}

export function updatePassword(eventValue) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_PASSWORD,
    password: eventValue
  }
}
```

And my reducer as:

```
//reason for leaving userInfo empty is so it doesn't interfere with TextInput placeholder

const initialState = {
  userInfo:{
  }
}

function inputReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case UPDATE_USERNAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        username: action.username
      }

    case UPDATE_PASSWORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        password: action.password
      }

   default:
     return state

  }
}
```

And the parent component renders the element `<CustomInput/>`:

```
//userInfo is the object from the inputReducer

  <CustomInput
    placeholder='Username'
    userProp={userInfo.username}
    actions={this.props.actions}
  />

  <CustomInput
    placeholder='Password'
    userProp={userInfo.password}
    actions={this.props.actions}
  />
```

And `<InputNormal/>` does the action call:

```
  _chooseInput(event){
    switch(this.props.placeholder){
      case "Username":
        this.props.actions.updateUsername(event.target.value)
        break
      case "Password":
        this.props.actions.updatePassword(event.target.value)
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }

  render() {
    var pr = this.props;

    return (
      <TextInput
        style={{fontWeight: 'bold', height: 20.5, color: '#999999'}}
        palceholderStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}
        placeholderTextColor='#999999'
        placeholder={pr.placeholder}
        onChange={this._chooseInput.bind(this)}
        value={pr.userProp}
      />
    );
  }
```

And once text is entered, it is updated as `undefined`. When I entered in a test string `test` in place of `event.target.value` the userInfo state updates correctly.

**The following is the log (with `username: undefined` as shown):**

[image]

The logic all seem to make sense but why does it update as `undefined`? Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you console.log the value of eventValue before returning an action, is the data correct or undefined as well?

Answer (score 0):

Since You use `onChange` to retrieve the text from input, You need get from `event.nativeEvent` object. It is hidden under `text` identifier.

In that case:

```
_chooseInput(event) {
  const { nativeEvent: { text } } = event;
  switch(this.props.placeholder){
    case "Username":
      this.props.actions.updateUsername(text)
      break
    case "Password":
      this.props.actions.updatePassword(text)
      break
    default:
      break
  }
}
```

Alternative is to use `onChangeText` that passes a string to your handler function instead of an `Event`. So You will end up in:

```
_chooseInput(text) {
  switch(this.props.placeholder){
    case "Username":
      this.props.actions.updateUsername(text)
      break
    case "Password":
      this.props.actions.updatePassword(text)
      break
    default:
      break
  }
}

// mark that You have a type in "palceholderStyle", should be "placeholderStyle"
render() {
  var pr = this.props;

  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{fontWeight: 'bold', height: 20.5, color: '#999999'}}
      placeholderStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}
      placeholderTextColor='#999999'
      placeholder={pr.placeholder}
      onChangeText ={this._chooseInput.bind(this)}
      value={pr.userProp}
    />
  );
}
```

To get more, look at the:

- [onChange doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange)
- [onChangeText doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext)